# GitLab syntax highlighting question: red highlight on class

Tags: syntax, gitlab, syntax-highlighting

Anyone has any idea why in my `scss` document these two classes `.age` and `.organisation` have a red highlight to them? I have looked all over the place but can't figure out what the problem is. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems GitLab marks them differently depending on what one uses two colons or one. [This](https://css-tricks.com/to-double-colon-or-not-do-double-colon/) is for reference for what the difference is.